# Flask: Use a End-Point in a subdomain

Tags: python, flask, subdomain

I have a Flask Website which have:

```py
from flask import Flask
import jsonify
#... Any Other Import ...

app = Flask(__name__)

#... Any Other Initialization ...

@app.route('/api/<string:id>'):
def API(id):
    id = api.id()
    return jsonify("Any API")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Please let me know how to run the api in a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```py
from flask import Flask
import jsonify
#... Any Other Import ...

app = Flask(__name__)

#... Any Other Initialization ...

@app.route('/<string:id>', subdomain='api'):
def API(id):
    id = api.id()
    return jsonify("Any API")
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

[image: Rajdeep, a Full-Stack Python Developer]